# Why does Google add o's to their name to signify result pages?

Tags: search, labels, google

[image]
[image]

**Why have the word Google spelled with ten o's? Why have it there at all?**

The red letter o signifies the page you are on in correlation to the page number below it, but why have that connection in the first place? What purpose does this serve besides having the company's name further associated with the action of searching?

Comment: Well, what do you expect?

Comment: The red 'O' is easier to see than just highlighting the number.

Comment: Why don't you ask Google?

Comment: We can't answer these questions as only Google have the answer. We can only speculate (hence this has been put on hold for being 'opinion based'). You should find a Google product forum for such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few reasons;

- "O" is part of their name and during the early years, they needed
  gimmicks like these to help users memories their brand. That "job" has been done well and is no longer needed though.
- Current "O" has a high contrast and in a glance, you know which page you are on. However, the same could've been achieved using letters underneath.